# Hiding login link when user is logged in

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security, thymeleaf, h2

I'm almost finished with a project of mine (bare with me I'm a beginner). I want to hide the login link when  a role (admin or user) is logged into database. I also want to display a link called "add grade" only when Admin(Manager) is logged in. I am working with spring boot, thymeleaf, spring security5 and h2 & jdbc.

To summarize I want to hide or show HTML based on user's role

UPDATE: it works when I use the <div sec:authorize... for "add grade" link. Now just trying to figure how to hide login link when any role is logged in.

Comment: Can you add what you have now and why you think it is not "clean" ?

Comment: Hey Wim, updated my question, I had a way. I put a div around the login in link and gave it authority to a manager and a user. As for the add grade I did the same procedure but gave authority to the Manager (Admin) only. This way still gave me an error.

Comment: Can you add what error exactly you got ?

Comment: I fixed the error, (it was silly syntax error). Now I am left with hiding the log in link when any role is logged in.

Answer (score 2):

This is my typical code for either including or not including in a navbar:

```xml
              <li th:ref="navbar-item" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
                <a th:text="'Login'" th:href="@{/login}"/>
              </li>
```

If you mean don't include by "hide", wrap your link in a `th:block`.

```xml
              <th:block sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
                <a th:text="'Login'" th:href="@{/login}"/>
              </th:block>
```